# iPad Pro keeps repeatedly restarting

Tags: ipad, restart, ios

My iPad Pro(9.7" cellular) keeps restarting and sometimes I won’t even get to finish entering the passcode.

### Troubleshooting

- I have done a hard reset
- I have not installed any new apps
- I have updated all my apps
- I have done a factory reset
- I have updated to the latest iOS 12

But the problem still persists

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: stuck power button ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I haven’t thought about that. Let me check the power button.

Comment: I have discovered that  it restarts when i just give it a slight hit on my palm it turns off and restarts. So its responding to a slight force every time.

Comment: there you have it, misery solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused my hardware problem.

Like malfunctioning power Button.

Flaky contact makes it run reset and loop.

Check and replace the hardware.